# Setting up Subversion Server on Mac OS mountain lion (have access via browser, but un-able to checkout from subversion)

Tags: macos, installation, osx-mountain-lion, svn-server

Some details (maybe it would be usefull for some guys):

**On board**: mac mini + mountain lion + Server.app.

**Problem**:
I do have access to my subversion repo via browser, but do not have access to it via command line to checkout (for example).

***I've done***:

1. Got **mod_dav_svn.so** and **mod_authz_svn.so** from Mac OS Lion and put it into `/usr/libexec/apache2`
2. Next, created **com.site.svn.plist** in **/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/webapps**:

   > ```
   > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   > <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   > <plist version="1.0">
   >
   > <dict> 
   >   <key>name</key>
   >   <string>com.site.svn</string>
   >   <key>includeFiles</key>
   >   <array>
   >       <string>/private/etc/apache2/svn_configs/svn_config.conf</string>
   >   </array>
   >     <key>requiredModuleNames</key>
   >   <array>
   >       <string>dav_svn_module</string>
   >       <string>authz_svn_module</string>
   >   </array>
   >   <key>sslPolicy</key>
   >   <integer>1</integer>
   >   </dict>
   > </plist>
   > ```
3. **I've added LoadModule(s)** for **mod_dav_svn.so** and **mod_authz_svn.so** into **/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf**:

   > ```
   > LoadModule dav_svn_module libexec/apache2/mod_dav_svn.so
   > LoadModule authz_svn_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_svn.so
   > ```
4. **I've created** **/private/etc/apache2/svn_configs/svn_config.conf**:

   > ```
   > <Location /svn/repo1>
   >
   >         DAV svn
   >         AuthName "Subversion auth"
   >         SVNPath /Users/someUser/Repositories/Repo1Repo
   >
   >         <Limit GET HEAD OPTIONS CONNECT POST PROPFIND PUT DELETE PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
   >                 Require group repo1users
   >         </Limit>
   >
   >         AuthType Basic
   >         Require group repo1users
   >
   > </Location>
   > ```
5. **I've executed** from the terminal:

> webappctl start com.site.svn

and after that I'm **able to reach** repo1 via `https://site/svn/repo1`

but when I'm trying to subversion checkout system gives me:

> ```
> >>>svn co https://site/svn/repo1
> Authentication realm: <https://site:443> UserWebDAV Gateway
> Password for 'someUser': 
> svn: access to 'https://site/svn/repo1' forbidden
> ```

**Do you have any clue why I have this situation ?**

P.S. Rights for

> ```
> /Users/someuser/Repositories
> /Users/someuser/Repositories/Repo1Repo
> /Users/someuser/Repositories/Repo1Repo/*
> ```

are **777**, **owner/group** - **_www:_www**

I've used for it - I read http://www.themacosxserveradmin.com/2011/01/lion-server-and-svn.html and tried to integrate it to mountain lion.

**Thank you for your thoughts.**

Answer (score 2):

Spent few days dealing with the same issue. While my configuration is not exactly the same should be close enough to help you accomplish what you are trying to do.
Was able to link the authentication issue to having WebDAV enabled for Wiki (in Server app). If you disable WebDAV support there things will start working.
In my case I chose to simply create additional listener in Apache on custom port (8080 or 8443) and placed all my SVN-related configuration instructions there, so everything is localized in one place.

Good luck!

Comment: did check that, could you give more details as like what files did you change, or something like process step by step as far as I wasn't able to resolve the issue :-(